# Nativescript TextField add char while typing in

Tags: properties, viewmodel, textfield, edit, nativescript

I need to add one char the the TextField while also typing in. I get typed chars from View Model Object.defineProperty getter/setter. What do I should do?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend going through [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in order to receive better answers. One important thing is to show us a code you are working with and what you have tried so far.

As for the question - are you trying to create two-way binding?
if so this is the basic scenario to do it with a text-field:

***page.ts***

```
import { EventData, Observable } from "data/observable";
import { Page } from "ui/page";

var vm = new Observable();

vm.set("msg", "default message");

export function navigatingTo(args: EventData) {
    var page = <Page>args.object;
    page.bindingContext = vm;
}
```

***page.xml***

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" navigatingTo="navigatingTo">
  <StackLayout>
    <TextView hint="" text="{{ msg }}" editable="true" />
    <TextField hint="" text="{{ msg }}" />
  </StackLayout>
</Page>
```